# What is the right way of setting member pointers to null in a singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton

In `myClass`, I have a pointer of type `helper`, and I would like to set it to `null`.

Can I initialize it to `null` in the `getInstance()` function, or can I set it to `null` pointer in the declaration itself?

What's the best way to set it to `null`?

```
class myClass
{
public:
    static myClass* getInstance();
    static void destroy();
    Helper* Helper_;
private:
    static myClass*  instancePtr_;
    // Private so that object can not be created outside
    myClass(){};
    ~myClass(){};
    myClass(const myClass&);
    myClass& operator =(const myClass&);
}

myClass* myClass::instancePtr_ = NULL;
myClass* myClass::getInstance()
{
    if (!instancePtr_)
    {
        instancePtr_ = new myClass;
    }
    return instancePtr_;
}
```

Comment: Do it in the constructor?

Comment: I'd suggest *not* writing singletons to begin with. They always end up being more pain than gain in the long run.

Comment: Yeah , it works..but is it the only way

Comment: ` myClass* myClass::instancePtr_ = NULL;` this is usually unnecessary. The globals and statics are all in a zeroed-out memory area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In myClass i have a pointer of type helper and i would like to set it to null.

You can initialize it in the declaration:

```
Helper* Helper_ = nullptr;
```

In pre-C++11 mode, initialize it in the constructor:

```
myClass() : Helper_(NULL) {};
```

You can also omit `NULL` initializer, turning it into [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), with the same effect:

```
myClass() : Helper_() {};
```

Comment: @LearningCpp You tagged the question with `c++11` tag.

Comment: Aah, apologies .am sorry for that .

Comment: And how to delete it, would not it be a memory leak if i don't delete it ?

Comment: @LearningCpp The best practice is to use plain pointers for as non-owning pointers only. Otherwise use a smart-pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr` or, in pre-C++11 `boost::unique_ptr`. And in that case you do not need to initialize it explicitly to `NULL`. Even better, store `Helper` by value, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom used in frameworks where the static initialization order fiasco would make life hard is to let the user construct the object explicitly within e.g. `main()`, and enforce the single instance if the class needs to be truly a singleton **or** if it's used as if it was a singleton. The constructor then should use the initializer list (the below is C++03):

```
// interface

class MyClassBase {};
class MyClass : private MyClassBase {
  MyClass(const MyClass &); /* = delete */
  MyClass & operator=(const MyClass &); /* = delete */
  static MyClassBase * m_instance;
  Helper * m_helper;
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();
  static MyClass * instance(); // only usable if there's no more than one instance
};
```

```
// implementation

static MyClassBase null;
MyClassBase * MyClass::m_instance;

MyClass::MyClass() : m_helper{0} {
  // optional if there truly can only be one instance
  assert(!m_instance); 
  // invalidate the global pointer if we're not a singleton anymore
  if (!m_instance)
    m_instance = this;
  else
    m_instance = &null;
}

MyClass * MyClass::instance() { 
  assert(m_instance != &m_null);
  return static_cast<MyClass*>(m_instance);
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
  if (m_instance != &null)
    m_instance = 0;
}
```

```
// use

int main() {
  MyClass my;
  ...
}
```

In C++11, you'd instead write:

```
class MyClassBase {};
class MyClass : private MyClassBase {
  MyClass(const MyClass &) = delete;
  MyClass & operator=(const MyClass &) = delete;
  static MyClassBase * m_instance;
  Helper * m_helper = {};
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();
  static MyClass * instance();
};

MyClass::MyClass() { ... }

MyClass::~MyClass() {
  if (m_instance != &null)
    m_instance = nullptr;
}
```